# Problem with MySQL JOIN query / COUNTs

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to display a list of cookbooks which have been tagged with a specific tag. This is working, except I cannot also display the number of times the tag has been applied to each book by different users. I would like to sort by this number so a book tagged 'baking' for example, by multiple users, would rank higher than a book tagged 'baking' by only one user.

Here is a slightly simplified list of tables:

Table 1: cookbooks

```
ID, Title, Author, etc.
```

Table 2: recipes

```
ID, recipe_title, recipe, cookbook_id
```

Table 3: recipe_reviews

```
ID, recipe_id, star_rating, comments
```

Table 4: book_tags

```
tag_id, tag_text
```

Table 5: book_user_tag

```
user_id, book_id, tag_id
```

This is the test query as currently written:

```
SELECT cookbooks.*, COUNT(DISTINCT recipe_reviews.ID) as numreviews, COUNT( book_user_tag.tag_id) as numtags, AVG(recipe_reviews.star_rating) as average, book_tags.tag_text 
          FROM cookbooks 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN recipes ON cookbooks.ID = recipes.cookbook_id 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN recipe_reviews ON recipes.ID = recipe_reviews.recipe_id 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN book_user_tag ON cookbooks.ID = book_user_tag.book_id
          INNER JOIN book_tags ON book_user_tag.tag_id = book_tags.tag_id
          WHERE book_user_tag.tag_id = 69
          GROUP BY cookbooks.ID
          ORDER BY numtags DESC
```

UPDATE: This query ended up working when I debugged it and realized that a DISTINCT was required on the second count, and that it was trying to count the wrong variable; should have been user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this, try a simple SELECT * and remove your GROUP BY clause and COUNT fields, this way you can see the raw data that is produced before it is grouped, you may find that your joins are not working as you expected.

Comment: Good advice! I sorted it out by breaking it down to basics and realized I was doing my COUNT on the wrong variable.